Save Excel on Mac file to Dropbox using VBA
I have a macro in Excel on Mac that exports a specific worksheet.
It works unless the specified file path for saving the file is in Dropbox.
I get

Run Time Error 1004" & "Method 'Save As' of object '_Workbook' failed."

Option Explicit

Public Sub ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV()

Dim wbkExport As Workbook
Dim shtToExport As Worksheet

Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PAL DATA")     'Sheet to export as CSV
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False                       'Possibly overwrite without asking
wbkExport.SaveAs FileName:="/real/file/path/usually/goes/here/PAL_DATA_EXPORTED.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub

I know Dropbox on Mac recently started using the Apple File Provider API, developed by Apple for iCloud Drive and now used by Dropbox, Google Drive, and I'm sure others. However the macro executes and the file saves as expected when the file path is to iCloud or Google Drive.
The macro was saving to a location on Dropbox until I moved the main working file to a different location on the same Mac.
I tried changing the file format, the path separator ("/" is correct for mac), and the path.
